# Moq method Setup without having to specify argument list

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

When setting up a Moq object to return a specific value regardless of input parameters I currently have to effectively write out the full signature, e.g.

`Mock.Get(myThing).Setup(x => x.DoThing(It.IsAny<Int32>(), It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Boolean>>())).Returns(false)`

This is a little tedious if there are multiple input parameters and I don't care about any of them, so is there a way that I can say It.IsAnyForAllInputParameters()?

Comment: What about overloads of that method - how should Moq handle them?

Comment: Oh yes, good point.  Long list of parameters it is then.  You should add that as an Answer and I'll give you an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the comment by Bernhard Hiller, if this would be possible, then the moq should know how to setup all the methods with the same name. This should not be a problem, unless they have different return types:

```
void Sum(int a, int b, ref int result)
{
    result = a + b;
}

int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Then if you want to Setup `Sum` method to return value 10, how should the moq proceed for the first `Sum` method?

Comment: Ideally, we would need to specify parameters only when there are multiple methods with the same name.